# How to determine review on Google Play?

Tags: android, comments, google-play, review

I have a game app. Sometimes it asks user to make a review on Google Play and user could get some game's points for 5-star review.
How to know was review added on Google Play by user or not?

P.S. There is a Google+ account connection in the app for user identification. I thought to parse Google Play reviews from the app page and compare them with user's google+ account (google id). But I think it's not the best realization.